# Leaflet.draw: How to draw Octagon/Hexadecagon or other regular polygon?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson, leaflet.draw

I do not believe my question can be answered with a few lines of code here, but maybe someone has written an extension to [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) which can be used for drawing a regular polygon in a similar way as you can draw a rectangle or circle with Leaflet.draw ?

What I want is a possibility do draw a regular polygon (e.g. an Octagon or Hexadecagon) 
in a similar way as drawing a circle with Leaflet.draw, i.e. clicking in the center and then dragging the size of it, but then it also should be able to create a geojson polygon instead of a geojson point (which is done for the circle).

The problem with the circle is that when you implement a Leaflet.draw event method such as 
`map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e)`
then you can use `e.layer.toGeoJSON()` to get the geoJson but it will become a point instead of a polygon.

That method `toGeoJSON` works great when having drawn a rectangle, since you will then get a polygon with the coordinates of the four corners, but since there is no "circle" feature in GIS vectors (e.g. geojson or shapefiles and so on), then when using the "toGeoJSON" method in Leaflet.draw the geojson will simply become a "point" instead of a polygon.

That is the reason why I want a regular polygon (more useful than a circle) which can approximate a circle with for example a Hexadecagon using 32 edges and vertices.

I am aware that a kind of a workaround solution could be to use the Circle and then calculate a polygon from the circle (e.g. with something like this: https://github.com/w8r/L.Circle.toPolygon )

However, what I really would want is to have it all integrated in the visual drawing so that the end user can see the actual polygon corners when doing the drawing, rather than looking at the circle when drawing an area but then actually persisting something else (the polygon) which is an approximation of the drawn area.